# Sufficient Statistic for Variance (Normal Distribution)

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance, mean, sufficient-statistics

Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

If $\mu$ is known and $\sigma^2$ is unknown, prove that $S^2$ is a sufficient statistics for $\sigma^2$.

Likelihood:

$$ L = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac12\sigma^2 \sum x_i^2\right) \cdot \exp\left(-(n-1)\frac{S^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{n(\bar x - \mu)^2)}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$

I did the working up until this step, but I’m not sure about how do we factorise this expression into one that doesn’t depend on the parameter ($\sigma^2$) and the other one with the sufficient statistic and the parameter.

I have just started to learn about sufficient statistics a few days ago, and I am quite confused with the factorisation method to derive the sufficient statistic. In particular, for the last term in the expression with xbar in it, are we to treat $\bar x$ as a function of the data? If so, how are we supposed to factorise this expression, such that we could isolate the data from the parameter and the sufficient statistic?

Comment: Welcome to this site! You can use Latex to format your post. Please check that I didn't introduced any typo when editing your post.

Comment: Analyze the situation in terms of the random variables $Y_i = X_i-\mu \sim N(0,\sigma^2),$ thereby making $\mu$ disappear entirely from the likelihood.

Comment: Hi, if we were to do what as you suggested, wouldn’t it imply that sum(Yi) would be a sufficient statistic for sigma^2? If so, how do we reason that it should follows that sample variance is also a sufficient statistic for sigma^2?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that sum(Yi^2) would be a sufficient statistic for sigma^2.

Comment: Warning: Assuming you define $S^2$ as$$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x_n)^2$$this statistic is NOT sufficient.

Comment: Hi Xi’an, that was precisely how I define S^2. Do you mean that S^2 is not a sufficient statistic for sigma^2?